# Dúvida de iniciante - espaço em branco entre o topo e a barra de navegação

Tags: html, css, webdesign

O código abaixo é de uma simples barra de navegação, o problema dela é que existe um espaço em branco entre o menu e o topo do navegador.

Encontrei 2 soluções, alterar o seletor `body` para `*` no arquivo css ou adicionar `margin: 0;` no seletor `nav ul {` ficando desta maneira:

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    background: black;
}
```

Qual seria a solução mais apropriada e por que isso acontece? Afinal, eu já defini a tag `body` com `margin: 0;`

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PORTIFÓLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: 'arial';
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    background: black;
}


nav li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}
```